# Why the JAR file compiled by Java SE, able to execute in Android

Tags: java, android

In Android OS, I am able to run several Java JAR files compiled under desktop environment. For instance, [jtransforms](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms)

May I know why is it so? I thought the JVM from Oracle and Dalvik VM from Google uses two different byte code formats? Why the JAR file compiled by Java SE able to execute in Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are simply including the jar file in your android project? Then it works, as during the build process it is converted (the same is done for your own class files!) to dex format. This is done with the dex (dx) tool. Using ADT in eclipse it is automatically done for you. It's available for manual use in the android sdk of course too:

Under `android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\dx.bat` if on windows.

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia, `dx` is used to convert compiled `.class` files into the `.dex` format.

Comment: What does a JIT compiler have to do with this? That is for the virtual machine, not the compiler.

Comment: I thought that would allow this to happen at runtime, but maybe that's not true so I'll remove it for now.

Answer (score 0):

`1. Java SE` `-` `Java (Swing + AWT)` = `Android`

2.`In 2005, when Java was undergoing changes, Android creator didnt wanted to base Android`
   `totally on Java`. `So they included JVM as the 1st compilation unit, thats the reason`
   `JRuby , Jython, etc can be used to write Android apps`. `And 2nd Compilation unit as Dalvik 
   Compiler`.

`3. So its quite natural that a jar file compiled under desktop environment works fine on Android.`